# Navigation Controller that doesn't use the whole screen

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation controller which I don't want to use up the whole screen. In particular, I want to put a logo image in a bar at the top of the screen. Unfortunately, the navigation controller doesn't seem to be designed this way. In interface builder, I can't make it take up part of a screen. How would you achieve the effect of a logo image up the top and a navigation controller taking up the rest of the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done this myself, but it should be pretty straight-forward. You'll need a wrapper view controller to be its parent (let's call it `MyWrapperViewController`), and its view hierarchy might ultimately look something like this:

```
UIView -+ (hooked up to the view outlet in MyWrapperViewController)
        |
        +-- UIView (Your logo goes here)
        |
        +-- UIView (The "child" navigation controller's view)
```

The logo view can be a `UIView`, or a `UIImageView`, or whatever class is appropriate for the content.

When you create a `UINavigationController` somewhere for your `MyWrapperViewController` class, you can resize its `view` `bounds` to something smaller than full-screen (perhaps the size of the screen minus the size of your logo, with an appropriate `origin` offset so it's below the logo), and then add it as a subview.

Comment: This mostly worked, but I ran into an issue with the top UIView [overlapping the status bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767066/layered-uiviewcontrollers-overlaps-status-bar)