# Layered UIViewControllers overlaps status bar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

Following [this tutorial](http://blog.jayway.com/2009/03/22/uitoolbars-in-iphone-os-2x/) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722450/navigation-controller-that-doesnt-use-the-whole-screen), I attempted to create a custom `UIViewController` containing a `UINavigationController`. This mostly worked, except that the controller takes up the full screen and so the status bar overlaps it. Downloading the tutorial's source and running it, I found that the tutorial had the same problem (it uses a `UITableViewController`). Further experimentation revealed that it works if the content of the custom controller is a `UILabelView` instead.

[image]

Comment: PS. I am aware that navigation controllers now support managing toolbars nicely, but that isn't the point of this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to change the `loadView` function of the `UIViewController` to set the frame of the view using: `[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]` instead of `contentView.frame`. I'm not sure whether this is the best solution and how this will interact if you attempt to put the custom view controller underneath another view controller.

Ideally, I would be be given the size I have to draw into inside the `loadView` method. Unfortunately, we aren't given this. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103089/where-to-determine-uiview-size) for more info.