# How does Apple make its controllers contain other controllers?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

The [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) gives the following warning regarding using View Controllers to manage part of a screen.

> Note: You should not use view
>   controllers to manage views that fill
>   only a part of their window—that is,
>   only part of the area defined by the
>   application content rectangle. If you
>   want to have an interface composed of
>   several smaller views, embed them all
>   in a single root view and manage that
>   view with your view controller.

Now the strange thing is that Apple breaks this advice. [UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/), [UISplitViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/) all go against this advice. There is a discussion on the [Apple forums](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2129903) about what can go wrong if you ignore this advice.

I found a [tutorial](http://blog.jayway.com/2009/03/22/uitoolbars-in-iphone-os-2x/) on how to do this, but the method had a problem with [overlapping the status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767066/layered-uiviewcontrollers-overlaps-status-bar) which had a fix that seemed kind of dodgy. Other questions have [solutions that appear kind of dodgy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526990/adding-a-uinavigationcontroller-as-a-subview-of-uiview) or [advise against doing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486832/how-to-add-an-uiviewcontrollers-view-as-subview).

So given the question is what method does Apple use for its own controllers?

Comment: Can you please post the link to the reference? I always create a viewController for small views despite they fill or do not fill the screen. Would like to check out the consequences and good practice, please post the link . . .

Comment: @Raj: I added a link at the top of my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They also say not to use autorelease pools, but there are `autorelease` statements throughout their samples. Stick with what's practical. Purity should probably be slightly secondary.

Answer (score 4):

Apple wrote UIKit, so they can do what they like.

There's a lot of stuff happening under the hood:

- view{Will,Did}{Appear,Disappear}
- View rotations (ugh, headache)
- UIViewControllerWrapperView, which is sometimes the parent of UIViewController.view. Or something.
- UIViewController.navigationController/tabBarController/parentViewController/modalViewController
- Popovers are weird. I'm not sure how they fit in.

<strike>If you write your own views, you can probably get away with using UIViewController to control them</strike>, but don't expect all the magical behaviour that UIKit gives to a "proper" view controller.

**EDIT:** I probably shouldn't StackOverflow when it's late. I really mean something like this:

If a view is controlled by a UIViewController, the view controller should exist in the view controller hierarchy (i.e. functions like `presentModalViewController:animated:`). This allows UIKit to handle the complicated bits.

When you use something like `[fooSubview addSubview:viewController.view]`, UIKit may not do all the things it's supposed to do. What retains `viewController`? What happens if there's a memory warning and fooSubview gets unloaded?

If you set something like `viewController.view.frame = (CGRect){{0,0},{320,480}}`, you're asking for trouble too: UIViewController sets the frame depending on the current status/navigation/tab/etc bar. It might re-set it, or it might use the frame to decide how to lay out view controllers that you push on top (I've noticed this behaviour; it's messy). If you change `viewController.view.transform`, strange things can happen on view rotations, since the view transform is what UIViewController uses for orientation (along with the status bar and a pile of other things).

There's only one well-supported exception I know of:

```
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

(In fact, you can stick viewController.view inside a full-window view inside the window; I'm not sure how that works.)

I think in OS 4.0+ you're supposed to set `window.rootViewController = viewController` instead.